# Я(,) наверное(,) влюблен

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Является ли слово "наверное" в предложении "Я наверное влюблен" вводным? Или в данном случае "наверное" — член предложения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае *наверное* может быть и вводным словом, и наречием (обстоятельством):

> Я, наверное, влюблен. *(То есть "возможно, скорее всего".)*
>
> Я наверное влюблен. *(То есть "наверняка, точно".)*

Answer (score 0):

Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова:

НАВЕРНО; НАВЕРНОЕ. I. нареч. Несомненно, верно, точно. *Я это знаю н.* II. вводн. сл. По всей вероятности. *Он, н., опаздывает. Ты, н., знаешь этого писателя.*

(Интересно, что Кузнецов первым значением дает явно устаревающее или даже устаревшее).